# How do I explain work experience in a different field on my SOP?

Tags: job, statement-of-purpose

I want to pursue a masters degree in Electrical Engineering. I have a bachelor's degree in Electrical and Electronics Engineering, but I have two years experience as a software engineer. I want to state the reason for shifting from EEE to software in my SOP, but the main reason was purely financial; to clear my loans that I took up for my undergrad. The software job paid me thrice the amount of the Electrical Jobs. How do I explain this on my SOP? Can I state any other reason that sounds better compared to financial motives?

Comment: Are you sure this is even such a big issue? Those fields are still very close actually. Most of the engineers I know work in slightly different fields than their University major (not even counting all those working in sales).

Comment: @user7019377 I am unsure if not stating the reason for a job in a different field could be a potential reason for rejection

Answer (score 1):

There are many people who do exactly this - many have worked in a field that is almost completely unrelated to the subject(s) that they are researching.  There is a major opportunity to emphasise the demonstrable [tranferable skills](http://www.careers.qut.edu.au/student/resource/transferable.pdf) that you developed from your work that would benefit your research.

In your situation, as with many similar circumstances, specific examples of technical skills that you used and developed as working as a software engineer that would be relevant in your research in electrical engineering.